# Azure Monitor - Graph and alert usage (current size / total size) for service bus namespaces

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-monitoring

As the title implies, I'd like to create graphs and alerts for a "total usage" metric, but it seems like that metric isn't one that's already provided by the service. One half of the equation, current size, is provided already. But I cannot seem to figure out how to get the maximum size of a queue as well. Can I get this myself with a more advanced query?

Comment: service bus queue varies from 1GB to 80GB  defined upon creation of a queue and [enabling partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning) .

Alternatively, you can refer the overview of the service bus queue to identify the current queue size & Maximum queue size as shown in below. 
[enter link description here](https://imgur.com/jXJbU3M

Comment: Are you recording those logs from service bus queue using diagnostics  to log analytic workspace & trying to pull the queue size ?